# I need a regex for name validation with java

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hello i need a regex for name validation in java. Both first and last names are in one string.
both names need to be capitalized and allow hyphenated names.

valid:
John Smith, John-Doe Smith, John Smith-Doe

invalid:
john smith, John-doe Smith, John Smith-doe

so far i have tried this:

```
[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}\s[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]{0,40}
```

but can't get it to catch if the name after the dash starts with lowercase

Comment: that's because a small letter isn't found in the [A-Z] part of your regex. You'll need to adjust that, so it can find lower case letters as well

Comment: Is `John-Smith-Doe` valid or not?  How about `John Smith-Doe-Foo`?

Comment: I What about James O'Brien?  Are you sure you want to try telling people their names are invalid?  Better to just separate Family Name, Given Name, and force the first character of both fields to capital letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use repeated groups that start with an uppercase A-Z, and match a whitespace or `-` in between.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}(?:[\h-][A-Z][a-z]{0,40})*(?:,\h*[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}(?:[\h-][A-Z][a-z]{0,40})*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wzVfT/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "^[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}(?:[\\h-][A-Z][a-z]{0,40})*(?:,\\h*[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}(?:[\\h-][A-Z][a-z]{0,40})*)*$";
```

Answer (score 2):

*a slightly shorter regex would be*

```
String regex = "[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}(?:[-\\h][A-Z][a-z]{0,40}){1,2}";
```

*… with this change, Irish names (eg. Peter O’Toole) are also treated correctly*

```
String regex = "[A-Z][a-z]{0,20}(?:[-\\h][A-Z](?:'[A-Z])?[a-z]{0,40}){1,2}";
```